# Corona/Lua - How to print text in 3 columns

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am fairly new with Lua and Corona so I can't get the logic just yet.

I have data that look like this (but the list is created dynamically):

```
cat
dog
egg
want
gone
bone
goner
bones
effort
effect
```

But I want it to look like this on-screen (notice that the list is arranged by number of letters):

```
cat   gone   effort
dog   bone   effect
egg   goner
want  bones
```

The list can be longer or shorter, but I wish to keep it at 3 columns. How can I do this?

Regards,

John

Comment: Are you talking about how to print this to Lua IO stuff, or how to do this in some kind of Corona GUI widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3 Corona display.newText() side by side...

Or you can format the string that way using Lua itself, using the [[ ]]

```
local myString = [[
123    1234     12345
123    1234     12345
123    1234     123456
1234   1234     123456
]]
```